# Project new values from existing value

Tags: f#

I'm writing my very first F# program, the aim being simply to learn F#.

What I want to is provide a list of dates, and attributes (e.g.DayOfWeek, DayOfMonth) of those dates. I have managed to provide the list of dates and I know that the .net Framework gives me everything I need to extract all the attributes, I just can't figure out how to add the attribute as new columns in my list.
Here's what I have so far:

```
type Span = Span of TimeSpan with
 static member (+) (d:DateTime, Span wrapper) = d + wrapper //this is defining the + operator
 static member Zero = Span(new TimeSpan(0L))

type Dates() = 

 let a = DateTime.Parse("01/12/2013")
 let b  =DateTime.Parse("02/12/2013")
 let ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0)
 member this.Get() = [a .. Span(ts) .. b]

let mydates = new Dates()
mydates.Get()
```

When I run that code I get a list of DateTime values, with 2 records in the list. I can now do something like this:

```
mydates.Get() |> List.map (fun x -> x.DayOfWeek);;
```

which returns:

> val it : DayOfWeek list = [Sunday; Monday]

or

```
mydates.Get() |> List.map (fun x -> x.DayOfYear);;
```

which returns:

> val it : int list = [335; 336]

That's all great, however what I would like to do is project a list that has 2 "columns" (if columns is the right word) so that my output is (something like):

> val it : int list = [(Sunday,335); (Monday,336)]

I hope that explains what I'm after.

thanks

Jamie

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem, all your code appears to run fine, do you want to filter the output of `Get()`

Comment: To create a new list of values from an existing list you would do something like this: `[for x in 1..5 -> x * x]`. This creates a list of squares of x, but that part can be replaced with whatever projection you want.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you give us three lines of what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Hi folks, Thank you very much for the replies so far. I really didn't do a good job of explaining this did I? So, I've amended it to hopefully explain a little better what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, the solution is simple, make the map return a tuple like so

```
mydates.Get() |> List.map (fun x -> x.DayOfWeek,x.DayOfYear);;
```

Comment: Yes, that is indeed ridiculously simple :) Thank you John, hopefully you can tell that I'm a real newbie here.

Comment: Hi John, a follow-up question if I may. What I didn't say earlier is that I'm wrapping as a Web API meaning ultimately this thing returns JSON. problem I'm having is that the JSON fields have names like m_item1, m_Item3, etc... rather than DayOfWeek, DayOfYear, etc.. Is there a way to alias the elements of the tuple (i.e. give them a meaningful name)?

Comment: You could use a record type - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx