# Can I convert a list of tuples into a list of records?

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```
open System
type Span = Span of TimeSpan with
  static member (+) (d:DateTime, Span wrapper) = d + wrapper //this is defining the + operator
  static member Zero = Span(new TimeSpan(0L))
let a = DateTime.Parse("01/12/2013")
let b = DateTime.Parse("03/12/2013")
let ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0)
[a .. Span(ts) .. b] |> List.map(fun x -> x, x.DayOfYear);;
```

It returns a list of tuples:

> val it : (System.DateTime * int) list =   [(01/12/2013 00:00:00, 335);
>   (02/12/2013 00:00:00, 336);    (03/12/2013 00:00:00, 337)]

I also have a record type defined as

```
type DateInfo = {DateandTime System.DateTime; dayOfYear int
```

I would like to convert my list of tuples into a list of DateInfo. Is that possible?

P.S. I've had a lot of previous help on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338670/project-new-values-from-existing-value) where someone provided a useful link regarding records however I haven't been able to figure out how to do what I need so I thought better to start a new thread here.

Comment: The [docs on records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233184.aspx) give examples of how to define and create instances of them.

Comment: What have you tried?  It's difficult to improve your understanding unless we can figure out where it's breaking down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't convert you list of tuples into records, but instead create the records right away:

```
[a .. Span(ts) .. b] |> List.map(fun x -> { DateandTime =x; dayOfYear =x.DayOfYear);;
```

Also the (+) operator with the generator seems a bit clunky, you might want to read up on [Seq.unfold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340363.aspx):

```
open System

type DateInfo = {
    DateandTime: System.DateTime
    dayOfYear: int
}

// be aware of different DateTime formats! your code breaks on different culterinfos..         
let a = new DateTime(2013, 12, 1);
let b = new DateTime(2013, 12, 3);

// Seq.unfold     
Seq.unfold (fun d -> if d < b then Some(d, d.AddDays(1.0)) else None) a
|> Seq.map (fun x -> { DateandTime=x; dayOfYear=x.DayOfYear})
|> Seq.toList // this is optional, you could use the Seq straight away as well
```

Comment: givdkamp, I'm blown away by quite how much awesomeness there is in your reply. Solved my problem, taught me loads in the process, and also gave me loads to go away and ponder as well. Seq.unfold, I'm on it. Thank you very very much. Regarding DateTime formats, yes, its a problem. Ultimately this is going to be wrapped in web API and those dates will be parameters to a web service call - haven't yet worked out how I'm gonna ensure valid date strings so for now I'm just using the first thing I wrote down. But yes, I acknowledge this needs to be improved.

Comment: glad to be of help. Next time tho also show what you tried and failed, they do have a point. Answered this one because you answered more questions than you asked.

Comment: Point taken. In this case I was stumped and didn't know *what* to try so it was a plea for help.