# Is it possible to add DivideByInt to existing types?

Tags: f#

Given a list of `TimeSpan` values, I would like to get the average `TimeSpan`. It would be elegant if I could just write it like this:

```
let durations = [TimeSpan.FromSeconds 4.; TimeSpan.FromSeconds 2.]
let avg = durations |> List.average
```

However, the compiler complains about this:

> The type 'TimeSpan' does not support the operator 'DivideByInt'

which is quite reasonable, since `TimeSpan` indeed doesn't define [DivideByInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353411.aspx).

To work around this issue, I attempted to extend `TimeSpan` like this (before using `List.average`):

```
type TimeSpan with
    static member DivideByInt (ts : TimeSpan) (i : int) = 
        (float ts.Ticks) / (float i) |> int64 |> TimeSpan.FromTicks
```

While this implementation seems to work correctly when used directly, it unfortunately doesn't seem to make the compiler happy when using `List.average`.

While I'm very much aware that I can use [List.averageBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353667.aspx), or just write a custom function to calculate the average of a list of `TimeSpan` values, I thought it'd be elegant if one could write `durations |> List.average`.

Is there any way to enable that syntax?

Comment: Does TimeSpan have a static member Zero? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353446.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You could use a wrapper on which the static members `DivideByInt`, `(+)` and `Zero` are defined. Duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338670/project-new-values-from-existing-value)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. See this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681142/static-extension-methods-supporting-member-constraints). In theory it might be possible to implement it in a future version of F#.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried to overload the op using

```
type TimeSpan with
member this.op_DivideByInt (ts : TimeSpan) (i : int) = 
    (float ts.Ticks) / (float i) |> int64 |> TimeSpan.FromTicks

let durations = [TimeSpan.FromSeconds 4.; TimeSpan.FromSeconds 2.]
let avg = durations |> List.average
```

I get the following compiler warning: 
`Extension members cannot provide operator overloads.  Consider defining the operator as part of the type definition instead.`

so it looks like we can't do this.

Comment: According to MSDN the members must be static:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353446.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: true, however the compiler didn't interpret my code as an operator until I tried it as an instance member.